# How to change the content of a span element to that of a variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm doing a rock paper scissors game and most of the coding is done except that I didn't add a functionality to the buttons, no matter what you click on you'll choose paper.

Before adding that functionality I want for the score to be updated on the webpage but whenever it tries to update I get :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'textContent' of null

```js
let choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"]
let localPlay = "paper"
let cpuChoice;
let scorePlayer = 0
let scoreCPU = 0
let playerPoints = document.getElementById("pScore")
let cpuPoints = document.getElementById("cScore")

function cpuPlay() {
  cpuChoice = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
  return cpuChoice
}

function gameConditions() {
  // DRAW
  if (localPlay === cpuChoice) {
    console.log("draw")

    // ROCK
  } else if (localPlay === choices[0] && cpuChoice === choices[1]) {
    scoreCPU = scoreCPU + 1
    return cpuPoints.textContent = scoreCPU;
    //cpu
  } else if (localPlay === choices[0] && cpuChoice === choices[2]) {
    scorePlayer = scorePlayer + 1
    return playerPoints.textContent = scorePlayer;
    //player

    // PAPER
  } else if (localPlay === choices[1] && cpuChoice === choices[0]) {
    scorePlayer = scorePlayer + 1
    return playerPoints.textContent = scorePlayer;
    //player
  } else if (localPlay === choices[1] && cpuChoice === choices[2]) {
    scoreCPU = scoreCPU + 1
    return cpuPoints.textContent = scoreCPU;
    //cpu

    // SCISSORS
  } else if (localPlay === choices[2] && cpuChoice === choices[0]) {
    scoreCPU = scoreCPU + 1
    return cpuPoints.textContent = scoreCPU;
    //cpu
  } else if (localPlay === choices[2] && cpuChoice === choices[1]) {
    scorePlayer = scorePlayer + 1
    return playerPoints.textContent = scorePlayer;
    //player
    // DEBUG
  } else {
    console.log("not working")
  }
}

function shoot() {
  cpuPlay();
  gameConditions();
  console.log(cpuChoice)
  imageChanger();
  console.log("Player score: " + scorePlayer)
  console.log("Cpu score: " + scoreCPU)
}

function imageChanger() {
  let cpuImage = document.getElementById("cpuImg")
  if (cpuChoice === choices[0]) {
    cpuImage.src = "https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/rock.png"
  } else if (cpuChoice === choices[1]) {
    cpuImage.src = "https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/paper.png"
  } else if (cpuChoice === choices[2]) {
    cpuImage.src = "https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/scissors.png"
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  background-color: #9f85db;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 24px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

.choices {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 175px;
  width: 175px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.choices img {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <title>Rock Paper Scissors</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./game.js"></script>
    <!--<link href="./style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">-->
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>

    <div class="score">
      <h3>Player score: <span id="pScore"> 0 </span></h3>
      <h3>Cpu score: <span id="cScore"> 0 </span> </h3>
    </div>

    <div class="cpu">
      <h2>Cpu has chosen :</h2>
      <div class="choices"><img id="cpuImg" src=""></div>
    </div>

    <div class="player">
      <h2>Choose one :</h2>

      <div class="choices">
        <img src="https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/rock.png" onclick="shoot();">
      </div>

      <div class="choices">
        <img src="https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/paper.png" onclick="shoot();">
      </div>

      <div class="choices">
        <img src="https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/images/scissors.png" onclick="shoot();">
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Here is my [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rodpa715/L3upna7d/11/) here is my [Github Repo](https://github.com/rodpa715/rock-paper-scissors) and here is the [GitHub Page](https://rodpa715.github.io/rock-paper-scissors/)

Does it have something to do with the fact that I'm trying to set the .textcontent with a variable?

Comment: maybe try and add your code in an event listener `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded, function() {YOUR CODE})` (and remove the `return`)

Comment: simplest solution possibly is to move the script import out of the head, and include it inside your body, at the end right before the body closing tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add your `script` tag inside body tag instead of head.

It will work!!!

Comment: So it will first load the page and then the .js but is there any difference if I add it in the end besides of loading priotrity?

Comment: Actually `body` will load `script` tag after `html` is loaded. But `head`  don't have this capability. Hence, always keep your `script` tag inside `body`. If you have any problem ahead fill free to reach me.

Answer (score 2):

This is most common problem with JS and HTML. JS will load before whole HTML, so when you trying to make a DOM variables, there is nothing (spans aren't loaded yet). So you can make a onLoad event, that will meke these variables, or don't make these variables, and setting value directly to spans.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
else if (localPlay === choices[0] && cpuChoice === choices[1]){
    scoreCPU = scoreCPU + 1
    cpuPoints.innerText = scoreCPU;
}
```